# How to check first radio button from the list?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

How to check first radio button by default in ejs when using for loop? Because currently by default last radio button is checked.

```
<% for (index=0; index < groups.length; index++){ %>
    <% if (groups[index][0] !=assignerID) { %>
        <input type="radio" id="<%= groups[index][0] %>" name="groupDetail" value="<%= groups[index] %>" checked="checked">
        <label for="<%= groups[index][0] %>"><%= groups[index][1] %></label><br>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You can do something like this `<%= index === 0 ? 'checked' : '' %>` instead of `checked="checked"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this `<%= index === 0 ? 'checked' : '' %>` instead of `checked="checked"`

Credit goes to: [firetozcevahir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12196329/firatozcevahir)

```
<% for (index=0; index < groups.length; index++){ %>
    <% if (groups[index][0] !=assignerID) { %>
        <input type="radio" id="<%= groups[index][0] %>" name="groupDetail" value="<%= groups[index] %>" <%= index === 0 ? 'checked' : '' %>>
        <label for="<%= groups[index][0] %>"><%= groups[index][1] %></label><br>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```